# 'libffi.so.5: cannot open shared object file' error while it can be located in LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: python, linux, ctypes

I need `ctypes` module in my python script. 
I'm running on Linux.
When I try to run the code `import ctypes`, I get the error: `libffi.so.5: cannot open shared object file`.
I do not have enough priveleges to do apt-install on my system, so I downloaded and build libffi from sources in my home directory and added the path to the `my/home/libffi/lib`, `my/home/libffi/lib/pkgconfig` and `my/home/libffi/lib64` directories to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable. Unfortunatelly I am still facing an error.
Am I looking for the wrong env variable or can't it be fixed with this approach?

Comment: `ctypes` comes with Python so it should just work with `import ctypes`.  Seems like an installation issue.

Comment: I assume you're using *Python 3.7*. Is there a *libffi.so.5* file in any of the *dir*s you added to *LD\_LIBRARY\_PATH*?

Comment: @CristiFati yes, it is. I solved the problem by asking the administrator to reinstall python and its dependencies... Thanks for attention